# directives handling routes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-routing

I'm new to angular and I'm looking for the right way to implement the following idea. I'm not sure if a directive is the right way in angular to solve it.

I need to provide a modal box which acts like a wizard. The first view shows a list of options or categories of options like

1. profile settings
2. integrations
   etc.

When clicking on `profile settings` it should show a form with all the settings and additionally should show a 'back' button to get one level up.

Selecting `integrations` will show a list of integrations like on [github](https://github.com/settings/applications) and each integration has its own form.

Every level will change the back button to get one level up.

My idea was to use routes like for a 'normal' page which gives us a shareable route to restore the same state if the link gets send to other users.

eg `#/settings/integration/github`

I read some blog posts that routes shouldn't be used in directives. Now I'm not sure if this is the right approach in angular.

Is it a good idea to use the `$routeProvider` in directives or is there a different approach in angular to archive this?